# Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition Design View Hangs

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

For past 30 minutes, when I go to Design view of Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition, it hangs there. I even tried repair reinstall, reboot (Windows 8 64bit) but same problem.

And it's a pain to drag controls onto the Design panel.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning the software is functioning normally. Perhaps it was just a glitch.